# Determine which process is taking most of disk bandwidth?

Tags: monitoring, io, disk

When the HDD indicator is blinking (for a long period), how could I know which process is taking most disk bandwidth?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`iotop`.](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/)

> Iotop is a Python program with a top like UI used to show of behalf of which process is the I/O going on. It requires Python ≥ 2.5 (or Python ≥ 2.4 with the ctypes module) and a Linux kernel ≥ 2.6.20 with the TASK_DELAY_ACCT CONFIG_TASKSTATS, TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING and CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS options on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As well as `iotop`, you can also use [`iostat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat).